# A rod inclined at angle 60° with the horizontal is dropped on the floor with initial velocity u. How to find axis of pure rotation after collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

Coefficient of restitution is $e$. Length of rod is $l$ and its mass is $m$. Before collision, rod performs pure translation, in vertically downward direction with velocity $u$

I know that after collision, COM (Centre of mass) will obtain vertical velocity of $eu$ and the impulse will equal $J=mu(1-e)$ . The body will perform general motion but I am struggling to identify the axis of rotation for the rotational component of this general motion.

I need this axis so that I can apply Angular impulse- angular momentum theorem  or angular momentum conservation to get angular velocity, depending upon whether the axis passes through COM or terminal end of rod respectively. I can then use these to obtain angular velocity of rotational motion of rod.

My intuition says that rod will perform rotation about COM and I read on another answer that the axis of rotation for any unhinged collision passes through COM but I would appreciate a complete explanation for this.

Also, will the presence/absence of friction influence the collision. My understanding is that friction will not affect the collision as no impulse will act along horizontal.

Comment: As far as I understand your intuition is correct: since the collision is elastic, the rod is unhinged in its rotation hence the pure axis of rotation should pass through its C.O.M

Comment: Do you mean to say "that friction will *not* affect the collision" in your last sentence?

Comment: Yes I made a typo. I meant to say friction will not affect the collision. I have corrected it now.

Comment: ... the explanation btw as far as I can see, is that in the rod COM frame it is simply "slammed" by a heavy object. If you slam a flying rod (true for rigid body in general too I guess) you won't be surprised to see it revolving around its COM :) But perhaps someone can give a better explanation.